# Sed to replace last character on condition

Tags: sed

I have a file which has following lines

```
172XI207    X123955 1
412XE401    XE05689 1
412XI402    XI9515  1
412XI403    XI06702 1
412XE404    XE75348 1
```

I want to replace last column to 2 if the first two characters in the second column matches to `XE`.

The result should be like below

```
172XI207    X123955 1
412XE401    XE05689 2
412XI402    XI9515  1
412XI403    XI06702 1
412XE404    XE75348 2
```

I wanted to use sed (not awk). Can someone please let me know how this can be acheived using sed?

Answer (score 2):

many sed commands take an address or address range (see the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) for the gory details).  Probably the most common command is `s` of course, but it is among those that take an address range, meaning it doesn't need to apply to every line.  An address range xan be a regular expression. The `s` command is:

```
{address}s/pattern/replacement/
```

For you the address - matching RE - is `/ XE/` (assuming your columns are space separarated; change that to a tab if necessary), the pattern is `1$` and the replacement `2`.  Therefore:

```
/ XE/s/1$/2/
```

or as a command line

```
sed -e '/ XE/s/1$/2/' < oldfile > newfile
```

EDIT: oops, second column, not start of line.

Answer (score 1):

This command should do the trick (providing you are looking at `myfile.txt`)

```
sed -e '/    XE/ s/1$/2//' myfile.txt
```

You can make sure your replacement is acted by adding the `-i` option which will modify the file in-place, make sure it's exactly what you are expecting before though.

Edit: based on question in comments, here is a command that matches on 3rd column and replaces on fifth.

```
sed -e 's/^\(\(\w\+\W\+\)\{2\}XE\(\w\+\W\+\)\{2\}\)1/\12/'
```

Or, as an alternative, you can first select the line and then substitute:

```
sed -e '/^\(\w\+\W\+\)\{2\}XE/ s/^\(\(\w\+\W\+\)\{4\}\)1/\12/'
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked but is it possible to have a column condition rather than searching for pattern in the line.  Because i have another file which has 5 columns and wanted to replace 5th column based on pattern in 3rd column. In some rows the same pattern might appear in second column, but i want to update 5th column only if 3rd column first two letters match the given pattern.

Comment: I'd say you better use awk for that job, as it's better on the idea of columns, you can use some {n} matching though.

Comment: @sanjanish: I updated my answer to answer your comment too. You should put it in your question though.